# How to reset record fetched from database at 11:59pm of Sunday (time before Monday starts)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am currently working on a php CodeIgniter project where I need to fetch data between current week Monday and current week Sunday and perform a count. I am able to fetch date of current week Monday and current week Sunday and also the count but facing problem in one additional thing that "I need to reset count at Sunday night as soon as date changes i.e. Sunday night 11:59PM so as soon as this time reaches if count was 40 then at 12:00 am of Monday count should be restart from 0.
below is my function that I have written:

```
    $this_week_start = date("Y-m-d" , strtotime("monday this week"));
    $this_week_end = date("Y-m-d" , strtotime("sunday this week"));
    $table = $this->db->table('orders');
    $table->select('*')->where("status_id = 16")->where("updated_at >= '$this_week_start'")->where("updated_at <= '$this_week_end'");
    $data = $table->get()->getResultArray();
    if ($data)
        return $data;
```

any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Surely thats AUTOMATIC. Your query will have the start and end time reset at midnight and you will I assume return NO Rows therefore the count will be 0

Comment: @Andy I think you misunderstood me completely, the code that is presented here is completely relevant . And furthermore I no where mentioned here that do work for me, in the end I explicitly mentioned "any help in this regard".  And to your point that code does not do any updates to database I also mentioned that I am fetching data count.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset record"? The code you've posted gets all of the data from the `orders` table where the `status_id = 16` and the `updated_at` time is between "Monday this week" and "Sunday this week". When you obtain that data with `->getResultsArray()` it will only give you whatever exists in the database matching those criteria. The data produced is dynamic so there's no need to "restart" anything. Re-running the script at any given point in time will produce dynamic data. If the returned data is in an array format, PHP indexes begin at 0 so there's no need to "restart" anything.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah but this piece of code doesn't return zero count at midnight but It resets at somewhere early morning.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this little test, the dates should roll correctly at midnight Sunday, to show the dates for the new week. Therefore the error can only be somewhere else in your code

```
# setup a fixed timestamp for ...
$midnight_minus1 = 1639958399;  // saturday at 23:59:59
$midnight        = 1639958400;  // sunday at 00:00:00
$midnight_plus1  = 1639958401;  // sunday at 00:00:01

echo 'AT midnight minus 1 second ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $midnight_minus1) . PHP_EOL;
$this_week_start = date("D - Y-m-d" , strtotime("monday this week", $midnight_minus1));
echo $this_week_start . PHP_EOL;
$this_week_end = date("D - Y-m-d" , strtotime("sunday this week", $midnight_minus1));
echo $this_week_end . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL . 'AT midnight precisely ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $midnight) . PHP_EOL;
$this_week_start = date("D - Y-m-d" , strtotime("monday this week", $midnight));
echo $this_week_start . PHP_EOL;
$this_week_end = date("D - Y-m-d" , strtotime("sunday this week", $midnight));
echo $this_week_end . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL . 'AT midnight plus 1 second ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $midnight_plus1) . PHP_EOL;
$this_week_start = date("D - Y-m-d" , strtotime("monday this week", $midnight_plus1));
echo $this_week_start . PHP_EOL;
$this_week_end = date("D - Y-m-d" , strtotime("sunday this week", $midnight_plus1));
echo $this_week_end . PHP_EOL;
```

RESULTS

```
AT midnight minus 1 second 2021-12-19 23:59:59
Mon - 2021-12-13
Sun - 2021-12-19

AT midnight precisely 2021-12-20 00:00:00
Mon - 2021-12-20
Sun - 2021-12-26

AT midnight plus 1 second 2021-12-20 00:00:01
Mon - 2021-12-20
Sun - 2021-12-26
```